# div float left causing overflow

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I have a div and I placed it like this

```
    <div id="d1" style="float: left; overflow:scroll;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="aa" Width="100%" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                    <div style="float: left">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:GridView ID="RepDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True" BackColor="White"
                                        BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3">

                                    </asp:GridView>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The problem is that the div is spreading to inside the footer that is placed in Master page.

So when I have two or three records in gridview it works ok but when the number of records increases the div with ID "d1" spread outside and invades the footer

What I am doing wrong, please help

Thanks

Comment: can you post a link to the problem, either with JSFiddle or the actual site if it's on a live site. It's a little hard to answer with just the above

Comment: you are having width as 100%, then why you are using float here?

Comment: @kiran ok now it's not 100% but still the problem persists

Comment: you have to remove float not width as you have overflow. just post a fiddle.. we will try to help you..

Comment: @kiran the problem is I am using gridview, when the data in gridview increases the overflow happens. How can I post gridview on fiddle?

Comment: Please explain the problem with further detail. Actual & expected?

Comment: Check if content is going out of containers. You can use web developer toolbar, firebug or something like that to do it. Or just add border to your divs and check if all boxes are where they should be.

Comment: @Bardo Yes the gridview going outside the containing div. How can I make div stretchable?

Comment: This type of problems usually are related to inconsistent floatings. Check that container div has flotation and, if it has, then start testing without any float on the related code. Then add them from outside blocks toward inside blocks, checking what happes in each step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I I solved it

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; border-style:solid">

    <div style=" border-style:solid; border-color:Red; width:60%; float:left;">
```

with overflow:hidden in containing div